# How to set the same number of data points in a Line Chart?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, charts, datapoint

I have multiple series which share the same x-axis but some values are repeated as they have different number of data points. Since this is the case I want to set the same number of data points for all my series.

Is setting empty data points a solution to make all series have the same number of data points or are there any other solutions? If setting empty data points is a solution, how do I use it? My series aren't fixed and vary according to user selection.

They follow:

```
Chart1.Series[i].XValueMember = "Receipt date";

Chart1.Series[i].YValueMembers = "AvgAgingDays";
```

Comment: I guess you have time-based data that is not aligned? In that case you should consider creating a stored procedure (or simply a function in case you do not use a DB) that does the averaging for a given interval size for each series.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Nope, instead I used cumulative values so that my chart looks readable . Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

*Is setting empty data points a solution?*

Well, it certainly will achieve the counts to be the same. But how it looks is a different matter.

- One question here is **where** do you inset them (X-Value), probably where they are missing, right?
- The other question is what `ChartType` do your series have? Here are a few typical types:

  - `Point, Bars, Columns`: That is fine, just make the `Color` of the 'empty' `Points` `Transparent`!
  - `Line, Area`: That is more tricky. You don't want gaps in the lines so you need to keep them visible. And you want the lines to go straight so you need to calculate the Y-Values from the neighbours. Simple for one missing Point, a little bit more work for larger gaps. Not possible for points missing at the start or end. Those should be invisible again..
  - `Spline`: Next to impossible to get really right. Either put in some more work or live with some inaccuracies!

If you have a `Line` chart, to fully document the situation, you may consider adding a `Point Serie`s on top with the same data, but with the missing `Points` invisible.

Btw: If you have correctly set the `XValueType` as `DateTime`, all this ought to be unnecessary, as then the missing dates won't matter and the `DataPoints` all sit at their respective dates. They only shift if you don't have a valid `X-Value` and/or fitting `XValueType`.

This is a rather comon mistake because at first it all looks fine but without setting the type it will be `string` and then you run into trouble when you want to act on the values or rely on their positions or even just format them..

Btw: While it is possible to `AddXY` the missing points afterwards, it makes things **a lot** easier if you can detect and add them **while** adding the real points..